# converting tuple to set for use in if-in statement in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, set, tuples

i have a tuple which looks like this `b (u'3.7', 9023)`. i want to use it in the following statement :

```
 if list(self.ballot_number) == msg.ballot_number and b in waitfor:
          print "hello"
```

i have checked and the ballotnumber section of the if condition is worrking fine. it's the second part that's not returning true. the waitfor set looks like this : `set([((u'3.0', 9002), (u'3.1', 9005), (u'3.2', 9008), (u'3.3', 9011), (u'3.4', 9014), (u'3.5', 9017), (u'3.6', 9020), (u'3.7', 9023))])`.

**The value of tuple are there in the set but they are not able to match it probably because of different data types**. **i don't want to split the tuple into individual elements** as i have to use it collectively later in the code. How can i run my if statement?

**building of set**

```
waitfor = set()
    print "in scout"
    for a in self.acceptors:
      print "acceptor",a
      a = tuple(tuple(p) for p in self.acceptors)      
      waitfor.add(a)
      print "waitfor",waitfor
```

Comment: `waitfor` appears to be a set of one tuple or a bunch of pairs. So no pair is an element of that set. I suspect you really wanted to build a set of pairs in this first place, and the code that builds that set is where the bug is, but you haven’t shown us that code.

Comment: The variable `waitfor` is a set containing one tuple containing several tuples? If that's correct, you can do `b in next(iter(waitfor))[0]`

Comment: If that set is actually correct/useful, but just not useful _here_, you can do something like `any(b in elem for elem in waitfor)`. But of course that’s a linear search. Maybe what you really want is to build a flat set for searching, like `waitset = {pair for tup in waitfor for pair in tup}`, and then you can do `b in waitset`. But again, I think the most likely thing is just that you built the set wrong.

Comment: @jdehesa There’s no list. The repr for a set in older Python versions is `set([elem, elem, ...])`, because the set constructor takes a list (or other iterable) of elements.

Comment: @abarnert  i have added the code for building the set

Comment: also, try changing your code to this: `if (list(self.ballot_number) == msg.ballot_number) and (b in waitfor):`. Notice the parentheses, this is to avoid chained comparisons.

Comment: @jpp unfortunately it does not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you’re not building the set that it seems you think you’re building, and as a result it can’t be used the way you want to use it.

Your code does this:

```
waitfor = set()
print "in scout"
for a in self.acceptors:
  print "acceptor",a
  a = tuple(tuple(p) for p in self.acceptors)      
  waitfor.add(a)
  print "waitfor",waitfor
```

So, for each acceptor, you’re not adding that acceptor to the set, you’re adding the tuple of all acceptors to the set. You do this over and over, but because it’s a set, and you’re adding the same tuple over and over, you end up with just one element, that big tuple of all of the acceptors. Which is exactly what you see—notice the extra parentheses in your output, and the fact that if you print out `len(waitfor)` it’s just 1.

And this means that none of the `p` values you later check with `p in waitfor` are going to be in `waitfor`, because the only thing that’s actually in it is the giant tuple that contains all those pairs, not any of the pairs itself.

It’s like adding “The State of California” to a phonebook millions of times, instead of adding the millions of Californians, and then asking “Is Jerry Brown in the phonebook?” No, he’s not. There’s no bug in how you’re searching the phonebook; the bug was in creating the phonebook. So that’s the part you need to fix.

So, what you want is:

```
waitfor = set()
print "in scout"
for a in self.acceptors:
  print "acceptor",a
  waitfor.add(tuple(a))
print "waitfor",waitfor
```

Or, more simply, this one-liner:

```
print “in scout”
waitfor = set(tuple(p) for p in self.acceptors)
print “waitfor”, waitfor
```

Or, if your version of Python is new enough for set comprehensions (I think that means 2.7, but don’t quote me on that), it’s slightly more readable:

```
print “in scout”
waitfor = {tuple(p) for p in self.acceptors}
print “waitfor”, waitfor
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got too many brackets in your set, so it's only looking for a single element.

```
len(waitfor)
# 1
```

If you try:

```
waitfor = set([(u'3.0', 9002), (u'3.1', 9005), (u'3.2', 9008), (u'3.3', 9011), (u'3.4', 9014), (u'3.5', 9017), (u'3.6', 9020), (u'3.7', 9023)])
```

Then your test:

```
(u'3.7', 9023) in waitfor
# True
```

Will work!

Comment: i am automatically adding values to set